# Jquery dynamic pagination with append divs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, pagination

Ummmm... I am trying something but not sure how to "finish" it.  I am adding `<div>`'s to a form by using `append()` that bit is not a problem.  I am trying to "create" each div as a "new page", therefore as I add a `div` I hide the previous `div`. example:

```
<form class="paginatedform" >
<div id="page_1" class="paginatedformpage clearfix">Content in here </div>
</form>
```

Then I "add a new page" like this:

```
$('#addpage').click(function(){
var newid = $('.paginatedform').length;
var nextid = newid+1;
var previd = newid;
$('#page_'+previd+'').hide();
$('.paginatedform').append('<div id="page_'+nextid+'" class="paginatedformpage clearfix">Content in here </div>');      
});
```

That lot "works" OK may not be the "best/prettiest", but it does work.

What I want/need to do is add a "back/next" link so you can "move between the pages (div's)"

I add the "links" like this: (actually contained in the code above but moved to give some form of "timeline" here

```
if(newid ==1 ) { $('#pagepagination').append('<a href="#" class="pgbk">back</a>'); }
if(newid ==2 ) { $('#pagepagination').append('<a href="#" class="pgnxt">next</a>'); }
```

the "overall" html looks like this:

```
<form class="paginatedform" >
<div id="page_1" class="paginatedformpage clearfix">Content in here </div>
<div id="pagepagination"></div>
</form>
```

BUT .. if I use (alert just to test getting the prev id)

```
$('.pgbk').live('click',function(){
alert($('#pollpagination').prev('div').attr('id')); 
});
```

or

```
$('.pgnxt').live('click',function(){
alert($('#pollpagination').prev('div').attr('id')); 
});
```

I always get the "first" id i.e. id="page_1" what I need to "find" id the "visible" id - i.e. page_"x".

Any ideas - hopefully it is "clear"

Comment: Where is #pollpagination element located? Can you post HTML for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I follow you, but if you are looking for a visible div amongst a set of divs in a container you can use :visible selector.
i.e.:

```
$('.pgbk').live('click',function(){ 
  alert($('#pollpagination').prev('div:visible').attr('id'));  
}); 


$('.pgnxt').live('click',function(){ 
  alert($('#pollpagination').next('div:visible').attr('id'));  //Changed prev to next
});
```

Comment: many thanks, thought "visible" came into it somewhere but I have never "done" visible before, so many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a toggle class mechanism, when you create/show a div you add to that a class like "visible-div" and when you hide a div you remove it.
This way it should be easy to know which is visibile and which is not. (just append a .visible-div to the selector)

Since you do the hiding/showing in the same place is would be also easy to keep the thing consistent.